# Why is there a gap between these two divs?

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to build a new [registration page on my site](http://velrania.com/register.php). The box was all 1 image with text and forms put on it.

I want to make the height change depending on the content (without stretching the image. So I cut off the top/bottom parts of the box, a small bit of the middle and forced it to repeat. This works almost perfectly

Now, the problem...There is a small gap inbetween .box and .boxbottom but I can't see where it would come from at all?

`margin: auto;` on all divs

`float: left;` helps a little bit but they weren't perfectly aligned

Here are the divs

```
.boxwrapper{
    width: 530px; 
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
            .boxtop{
                background-image: url(images/boxrepeattop.png); 
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                margin: auto;
                width: 100%;
                height: 45px;
            }

            .box{
                background-image: url(images/boxrepeat.png); 
                margin: auto;
                width: 100%;
                height: auto;
            }

            .boxbottom{
                background-image: url(images/boxrepeatbottom.png); 
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                margin: auto;
                width: 100%;
                height: 45px;
            }
```

and here's the HTML:

```
<div class="boxwrapper">
<div class="boxtop">
</div>
        <div class="box"> 
            <div class="contentbox">
</div>

</div
<div class="boxbottom">
</div>
</div>
```

Just like .boxtop and .box fit snuggly together, I'd like .box and .boxbottom to do the same

Comment: Are you missing a little of your code? I can't see a ```.boxbottom``` in your html?

Comment: @Ben  Please put your code inside the code snippet. So that it will become easy to reproduce the issue and provide the solution.

Answer (score 3):

The gap appearing on your [registration page](http://velrania.com/register.php) is due to the `margin-block-end: 1em;` css which is being added to `form` element. So to fix this just add a class with css `margin-block-end: 0;` to `form` tag.

Answer (score 1):

The form margin is pushing the divs apart at the bottom.  For a quick fix, you can put this style on your form 
    `margin-bottom: 0;`

Answer (score 1):

Add `margin 0` your `form` tag

```
.contentbox form{
  margin:0;
}
```